# Fun experiments I can do with my bridge camera?

Tags: shooting-technique, inspiration

This is a bit of a vague question so I'm not looking for a specific answer, just some ideas really.

I have a Canon sx510 and was wondering if there are any fun photography methods I could play with? Just something to produce interesting camera effects.

I've messed about with long exposure photography before but is there anything else I could play with using a bridge camera?

Any "wacky" methods would be greatly appreciate

Comment: Unfortunately, questions without specific answers aren't a good fit for Stack Exchange.

Comment: I know we have an older question that has some ideas, just having trouble finding it right now. Might want to start with the [inspiration] tag though.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Yep, i feared that :/

Comment: However, do feel free to jump into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/photography-chat) where people will be happy to brainstorm with you.

Comment: Lens is f3.4-5.8, 24-720mm | Lots of ideas here [**in this SE question**](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20933/what-can-be-done-using-a-18-55mm-lens/20941#20941) - related to a 18-55mm lens on a Canon 1000D. You have much more zoom, slower shutter response, worse noise performance, ... . AND much of the ideas in the answers there still relate. Note that there are a number of sample links from my answer. Note that the 'through the bars' type photos work bet at large aperture and distance to bars etc << focal length - so you have many opportunities with large zoom.

Comment: From above [Photo on left taken **through** mesh on right](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3biHu.jpg) , [get close](http://public.fotki.com/RussellMc/srs/pict855910190223r.html), New: 24mm marginal [try this](http://public.fotki.com/RussellMc/srs/pict722610190221.html#media) , [unusual contexts](http://images49.fotki.com/v606/photos/1/760471/7475499/PICT2832-vi.jpg) , [just a fountain](http://images57.fotki.com/v1354/filev2DB/48060/1/760471/7475499/000221arc102022_2_After_Domain1.jpg) , Long lens [lets you get these](http://images59.fotki.com/v255/fileG1hU/48060/1/760471/7475499/PICT3515rrLetsgo.jpg)

Comment: Ideas etc [roll with scroll wheel](http://public.fotki.com/RussellMc/srs/?view=roll#4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such experiments are often carried out not only to have fun, but also to broaden set of skills in techniques available.

An easy way to devise such an experiment would go like this:

- Think of an aspect in your usual process of making pictures.
- Try reasoning why you do that.
- Now you can deduce what could be achieved when doing the opposite.
- Verify your theory by doing the opposite and achieving the effect.

For example, if you usually take pictures using only available light, think what you could achieve by adding all the light yourself, and try making a light painting. If you usually take sharp pictures, ponder what blurred images might convey, and try doing that. If you're used to photograph people by focusing on their face, see if targeting their hands might bring something unique. Etc.

Comment: Good answer, maybe it is a good idea to create a community wiki that lists common "experiments".

Comment: In regards to community wiki: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1008/please-dont-use-community-wiki-as-a-flag-for-more-subjective-questions